# char argv[ ][ ] as main function argument, why not?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, arguments

I have learned from an online class that, both `char **argv` and `char *argv[ ]` can be used as an argument to `main`.

I also understand that they are effectively the same, they both declare argv as a "pointer (`*`) to a char pointer (`char *`)".

What makes `char argv[ ][ ]` invalid as an argument to `main`?

edit: Actually, is `char *argv[ ]` declaring an array instead of a pointer? So argv only decays to a pointer but is not one itself?

Comment: Because `char argv[][]` just isn't a valid declaration, no matter where you have it? And also that the system is passing a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) which can only be represented in C as a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I don't see `char argv[][]` anywhere, but could you tell me why is that?

Comment: A function parameter cannot declare an array.

Comment: `*argv[]` *is* an array: an array of pointers, aka a jagged array. The `char argv[ ][ ]` would require all the elements to be consecutive in memory, and all the rows to be the same length. So if one argument was "Y" and another was 99 characters, every row would need to be 100 elements.

Comment: Can I say the reason is that the main function wouldn't know _how much memory is needed_ because elements of `char argv[][]` could have different sizes? While in the case of `char *argv[ ]`, it is just the size of `char *`?

Comment: The answer to "What makes char argv[ ][ ] invalid as an argument to main?" is "it is the wrong type."

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude a pointer to an array of unknown size is possible (as a pointer to any incomplete type) and `char (*a)[]` is a valid declaration. `char a[][]` is not, but not because a pointer to an array of unknown size is somehow prohibited (it is not). It is invalid because a declaration has to be valid *before* the type is adjusted.

Comment: So `char **argv` and `char *argv[ ]` are not the same after all. The former is a pointer and the latter is an array.

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `char (*argv[])` is the same as `char *argv[]`. I think you meant `char (*argv)[]`?

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes, typo, thanks. I will redo it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `char (*argv)[]` is legal and possible; a pointer to an array of unknown size is allowed. There is no rule in C that a pointer has to point to a complete type. In contrast, `char argv[][]` nominally declares an array of arrays of unknown size, and that violates the constraint that the element type of an array shall not be an incomplete type (C 2018 6.7.6.2 1). Even though the array will be adjusted to be a pointer, the constraint may apply before the adjustment (there could be some latitude interpreting the C standard regarding this).

Comment: "So char **argv and char *argv[ ] are not the same after all." is incorrect. Remember that when declaring "array" arguments, the compiler treats them as pointer. For example an argument like `char a[]` is translated as `char *`. Now when declaring an array of pointers (like `char *argv[]`) the same thing applies. I.e. `char *argv[]` is exactly equal to `char **argv`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *`char (*argv)[]` is legal and possible; a pointer to an array of unknown size is allowed.*  But you can't dereference it to access the arguments.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It is the wrong type for a parameter to `main`, but, if it is a parameter to some other function, [it certainly can be dereferenced](https://godbolt.org/z/dexvGs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration of a parameter

```
char argv[ ][ ]
```

is invalid because the compiler needs to know the element type of the array that in this case is incomplete type `char[]`.

This declaration

```
char *argv[ ]
```

declares an incomplete array type with the element type `char *`.

If such a declaration is used as a function parameter declaration then it is implicitly adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the element type that is to the declaration

```
char **argv
```

Comment: Straight to the point and cleared up all my confusion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Getting into the weeds a bit:

> **6.7.6.2 Array declarators**
> ...
> 1    In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit
> an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
> expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
> have a value greater than zero. ***The element type shall not be an incomplete or function
> type***. The optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static` shall appear only in a
> declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost
> array type derivation.
> ...
> 4    ***If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type***. If the size is `*` instead of
> being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size,
> which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope;**143)**
> such arrays are nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression
> and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length
> array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type. (Variable length
> arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.)
> ...
> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 4    ***After adjustment, the parameters in a parameter type list in a function declarator that is
> part of a definition of that function shall not have incomplete type.***
> ...
> 7    ***A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation.*** If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

So, to unpack all of this:

```
char argv[];
```

declares `argv` as an array of unknown size of `char`.  This type is *incomplete*, so we cannot create an array of it with something like

```
char argv[][N];
```

and by extension, we can't create an array of unknown size of that element type:

```
char argv[][];
```

"But," I hear you say, "a parameter of type `char []` is adjusted to type `char *`, so why doesn't `char [][]` equate to `char **`?"

Because that's not how array decay works.  Let's start with a generic array declaration

```
T a[N];
```

The type of `a` is "N-element array of `T`", and in most contexts (including as a function parameter), its type is converted ("decays") or "adjusted" to "pointer to `T`", which gives us `T *a;`.

Now let's replace the type `T` with an array type `R [M]`.  Substituting that in for `T` gives us

```
R a[N][M];
```

The type of `a` is adjusted from "N-array of M-element array of `R`" to "pointer to M-element array of `R`", which gives us:

```
R (*a)[M];
```

**not**

```
R **a;
```

So `char argv[][]` will never decay to `char **`, it will decay to `char (*)[]` (which is an incomplete type and not allowed as a function parameter).  But we don't get that far, because `char argv[][]` is invalid all on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `char argv[ ][ ]`, it is thought every word to have the same amount of letters. Every argv[i], points to another `char *`, however, this all new `char *` do not need all to be the same size.

Moreover, if you run your code with `char argv[ ][ ]`, one error your compilor might show is: "declaration of 'argv' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first". In fact, the `int argc` argument contains the amount of arguments passed, that is how many char * will be allocated. However, there is not any information for the size of the `char *` every char * previusly allocated point to.